# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Geolocation> has no method 'hasLocationPermissions'

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I am facing a critical issue in my project. I am new in Appcelerator and i don't know how to fix it. This error is not getting in my machine. But the same got in another machine i am using.

First File

```
/**
 * Hepers for run-time permissions.
 */

// DEPENDENCIES
var dialogs = require('alloy/dialogs');

// PUBLIC INTERFACE
exports.requestLocationPermissions = requestLocationPermissions;

// PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
function requestLocationPermissions(authorizationType, callback) {

    // FIXME: Always returns false on Android 6
    // https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23135
    if (OS_IOS && !Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
        return callback({
            success : false,
            error : 'Location Services Disabled'
        });
    }

    // Permissions already granted
    if (Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(authorizationType)) {
        return callback({
            success : true
        });
    }

    // On iOS we can determine why we do not have permission
    if (OS_IOS) {

        if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesAuthorization === Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_RESTRICTED) {
            return callback({
                success : false,
                error : 'Your device policy does not allow Geolocation'
            });

        } else if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesAuthorization === Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_DENIED) {

            dialogs.confirm({
                title : 'You denied permission before',
                message : 'Tap Yes to open the Settings app to restore permissions, then try again.',
                callback : function() {
                    Ti.Platform.openURL(Ti.App.iOS.applicationOpenSettingsURL);
                }
            });

            // return success:false without an error since we've informed the user already
            return callback({
                success : false
            });
        }
    }

    // Request permission
    Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE, function(e) {

        if (!e.success) {
            return callback({
                success : false,
                error : e.error || 'Failed to request Location Permissions'
            });
        } else {
            callback({
                success : true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Second File (i am adding First (file Name : Permi) over here.

```
var Perm = require('Permi');

$.window.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    Perm.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_WHEN_IN_USE, function(e) {
        if (!e.success) {
            if (e.error) {
            }
            return;
        } else {
            Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
                if (e.success == false) {
                } else {
                    longitude = e.coords.longitude;
                    latitude = e.coords.latitude;

                    Titanium.Geolocation.reverseGeocoder(latitude, longitude, function(e) {
                        if (e.success) {
                            var places = e.places;
                            if (places && places.length) {
                                driverCity = places[0].city;
                                driverState = places[0].address;
                                annotation.title = e.places[0].displayAddress;
                            } else {
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    $.mapview.applyProperties({
                        mapType : Alloy.Globals.Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
                        region : {
                            latitude : latitude,
                            longitude : longitude,
                            latitudeDelta : 0.05,
                            longitudeDelta : 0.05,
                        },
                        animate : true,
                        regionFit : true,
                        userLocation : false,
                    });

                    var annotation = Alloy.Globals.Map.createAnnotation({
                        latitude : latitude,
                        longitude : longitude,
                        title : "The DEMO",
                        pincolor : Alloy.Globals.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
                        myid : 1
                    });
                    $.mapview.addAnnotation(annotation);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    this.removeEventListener('focus', arg);
});
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: On which Systems the issue occurs ? 
What ist the erfror Message ?

Comment: What Titanium SDK version are you using?

Comment: issue is with Mac. i am using Titanium SDK 5.2.2 GA

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Titanium SDK 5.4.0.GA` or later, since that versions include major changes regarding runtime-permission-handling on Android 6. See [`Ti.Android.requestPermissions`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android-method-requestPermissions) for more details.